# What kernel version comes with 11.04?

Tags: 11.04, kernel, versions

What kernel version comes with Ubuntu 11.04?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The upstream kernel version shipped in 11.04 is `2.6.38`.

You can look at the [package source](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-meta) in Launchpad to see other versions for each release.

Comment: For other Ubuntu versions, look at http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=linux-generic

Answer (score 4):

You can see which kernel version is currently running by checking these commands on terminal:

```
cat /proc/version
```

or

```
uname -r
```

or

```
uname -a
```