# Is it still recommended to apply the cgroups patch to Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: 13.04, kernel, patch

You sure remember about the ~200-line Linux kernel patch that does wonders. Since a better alternative came out (see link below) I've always been running it. Now that I'm about to install Ubuntu 13.04 from scratch, do you know if it's still recommended to apply this tweak? Or has raring already got optimized cgroups?

Thank you in advance!

[Getting the alternative to the 200-Line Linux Kernel patch to work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13928/getting-the-alternative-to-the-200-line-linux-kernel-patch-to-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Linus, this has not been needed since kernel version 2.6.38, which shipped with Ubuntu 11.04.

https://lkml.org/lkml/2011/1/18/322

[What kernel version comes with 11.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49546/what-kernel-version-comes-with-11-04)